# kineticjs passing parameter to callback function on onclick

Tags: jquery, canvas, kineticjs, layer

I know in jquery you can do it with something like
$('#btn').on('click',{param:'hello'},callback).  But with kinetic, I can't seem to do it. Any idea?

`var Stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ container: 'SurfaceCircle', width: 70, height: 68 });
 var topBtnLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({ id: 'top' });`

var topBtn = new Kinetic.Shape({ drawFunc: function (context) {
        context.moveTo(11, 10); context.arc(35, 34, 34, 1.25 * Math.PI, 1.75 * Math.PI, false); context.lineTo(44, 25); context.arc(35, 34, 12, 1.75 * Math.PI, 1.25 * Math.PI, true); context.lineTo(11, 10);
        context.fillStrokeShape(this); context.stroke()
    }, stroke: 'black', fill: 'yellow', strokeWidth: 2/*, id: 'top'*/, visible: true
    }); 
topBtnLayer.add(topBtn).**on('click tap',{param:'hello'}, callback);**


I will get runtime error **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'call'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Kinetic object eventing system (.on) takes only 2 parameters

- the event type to listen for (eg "click")
- the callback function

In the callback `this` is the Kinetic object.

Therefore, you can set a property on the object that will be accessible inside the callback.

```
topBtn.param="hello";

topBtn.on("click",function(){ alert(this.param); });  // click alerts "hello"
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/5QRAA/